# IOS Facebook SDK invite Missing App Link URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

IOS Facebook SDK invite user message when i trying to invite anyone.

> Missing App Link URL The app link used with this invite does not
>   contain an Android or IOS URL. Developers are required the enter a URL
>   for at last one platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppLinkUrl is not the url of your app in the market.

- You need to make your own appLinkUrl and put it in your
  info.plist(see:
  http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)
  that you'll be using for deepLinking.
- Then after you declare it on your info.plist, you must have at least
  an html web page where you can put the meta tags for the appLinks of
  ios or android(https://applinks.org). Take note the the appLinkUrl
  that you have put on your info.plist should be the same on your meta
  property="al:ios:url
- Debug your website url and check your meta tags using facebook url
  debugger. Press "Fetch new scrape information" to update the meta
  tags for any changes on it.
- Use the link of your webpage that has the meta tags and use it like
  on the sample on facebook docs

  > FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
  >   content.appLinkURL = [NSURL
  >   URLWithString:@"your_website_link_with_metatags"];
- Just need to make sure your meta tags have the right information.

Answer (score 6):

For Facebook SDK Invite, you need create a custom App Link. Facebook gave complete documentation for invites. Refer this link [to create App link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios). Facebook provides a App Link Tool to create your custom app link.
 In tool to create App Link, you need add some Custom URL scheme, App store ID and App name. Custom URL scheme looks like this: `youAppName://fbFacebookAppID`. We also add `fbFacebookAppID` in `.plist` under `URLScheme` in `URLTypes`