# Deep linking error in FBAppinvite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, deep-linking

I am trying to deep linking in FBAPPInvite but i gives me below error

[image]

I apply this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:@"1452" forKey:@"station_id"];
    [params setObject:@"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/radiostation.jpg" forKey:@"$og_image_url"];
    [params setObject:@"Check out my favorite station on iHeartRadio" forKey:@"$og_description"];
    [params setObject:@"Wild 94.9" forKey:@"$og_title"];

    [[Branch getInstance] getShortURLWithParams:params
                                     andChannel:@"facebook"
                                     andFeature:@"app_invite"
                                    andCallback:^(NSString *url, NSError* error) {
                                        FBSDKAppInviteDialog *inviteDialog = [FBSDKAppInviteDialog new];
                                        if ([inviteDialog canShow]) {
                                            inviteDialog.content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
                                            inviteDialog.content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
                                            inviteDialog.content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/host/zackspic.png"];

                                            [inviteDialog show];
                                        }
                                    }];
```

Comment: i add code that use in my appinvite method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution of my error

I set all parameter in branch.io

```
[[Branch getInstance] getShortURLWithParams:nil
                                     andChannel:@"facebook"
                                     andFeature:@"app_invite"
                                    andCallback:^(NSString *url, NSError* error) {
                                        FBSDKAppInviteDialog *inviteDialog = [FBSDKAppInviteDialog new];
                                        if ([inviteDialog canShow]) {
                                            inviteDialog.content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
                                            inviteDialog.content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
                                            inviteDialog.content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/host/zackspic.png"];

                                            [inviteDialog show];
                                        }
                                    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add meta tags of your app link url in your website.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <!-- Other headers -->
</head>
<!-- Other HTML content -->
</html>
</head>
```

OR

[IOS Facebook SDK invite Missing App Link URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143225/ios-facebook-sdk-invite-missing-app-link-url)